# How to populate an arbitrary struct in Go?

Tags: go

I want to create a function (in the example code called `gremlinResultToStruct()`) that takes an arbitrary struct and populates the values from a database query. Please note that the "Properties" key in the GremlinResultStruct are arbitrary too (that is why it is a `Properties map[string][]struct`)

**GOAL:**
I want `gremlinResultToStruct()` to populate the given struct based on its keys if they are available in the database results.

**WHY:**
I have hundreds of structs like Foo and Bar in my codebase and I want to have a single function that populates the struct needed in the code instead of creating semi-duplicate code.

**CODE:**
My code looks like this, it also contains the question:

```
// Gremlin Query result struct
type GremlinResult struct {
    AtType  string `json:"@type"`
    AtValue []struct {
        AtType  string `json:"@type"`
        AtValue struct {
            ID struct {
                AtType  string `json:"@type"`
                AtValue int    `json:"@value"`
            } `json:"id"`
            Label      string `json:"label"`
            Properties map[string][]struct { // <== IMPORTANT, CONTAINS A VALUE THAT IS THE EQUIVALENT OF THE KEY IN THE STRUCT (like Something, SomethingElse, EvenMoreSomethingElse or AndMoreSomethingElse)
                AtType  string `json:"@type"`
                AtValue struct {
                    ID struct {
                        AtType  string `json:"@type"`
                        AtValue int    `json:"@value"`
                    } `json:"id"`
                    Label string `json:"label"`
                    Value string `json:"value"`
                } `json:"@value"`
            } `json:"@properties"`
        } `json:"@value"`
    } `json:"@value"`
}

type Foo struct {
    Something     string
    SomethingElse bool
}

type Bar struct {
    EvenMoreSomethingElse string
    AndMoreSomethingElse  int
}

func gremlinResultToStruct(result *GremlinResult, ???){ // What to do at ???
    // How to itterate over the ??? key values (like: Something, SomethingElse, EvenMoreSomethingElse or AndMoreSomethingElse)

    // How to populate:
    // VARIABLE := Something, SomethingElse, EvenMoreSomethingElse or AndMoreSomethingElse
    // result.AtValue[0].AtValue.Properties[ VARIABLE ][0].AtValue.Value
}

func main {

    // Do stuff to get JSON results. HOW is not relevant for question
    dbResults := doDbStuffToPopulateResuts()

    // Create the results variable as gremlinResults struct
    results := GremlinResult{}

    // Unmarshall to this struct
    err = json.Unmarshal(dbResults, &results)

    // 1. Expected result should be "result-a" (see below)

    // Create the Foo struct
    foo := Foo{}

    // HERE IS MY QUESTION ABOUT (see function above)
    gremlinResultToStruct(&results, &foo)

    // NOW foo SHOULD HAVE Something and SomethingElse set
    fmt.Println(foo.Something, foo.SomethingElse)

    // 2. Expected result should be "result-b" (see below)

    // Create the Bar struct
    bar := Bar{}

    // HERE IS MY QUESTION ABOUT (see function above)
    gremlinResultToStruct(&results, &bar)

    // NOW foo SHOULD HAVE Something and SomethingElse set
    fmt.Println(bar.EvenMoreSomethingElse, bar.AndMoreSomethingElse)    

}
```

**Example JSON results.**

result-A:

```
{
    "@type": "g:List",
    "@value": [{
        "@type": "g:Vertex",
        "@value": {
            "id": {
                "@type": "g:Int64",
                "@value": 200
            },
            "label": "key",
            "properties": {
                "SomeThing": [{ // <== IMPORTANT, same as struct field in Foo{}
                    "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                    "@value": {
                        "id": {
                            "@type": "g:Int64",
                            "@value": 201
                        },
                        "value": true,
                        "label": "Write"
                    }
                }],
                "SomeThingElse": [{ // <== IMPORTANT, same as struct field in Foo{}
                    "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                    "@value": {
                        "id": {
                            "@type": "g:Int64",
                            "@value": 202
                        },
                        "value": true,
                        "label": "Read"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

result-B:

```
{
    "@type": "g:List",
    "@value": [{
        "@type": "g:Vertex",
        "@value": {
            "id": {
                "@type": "g:Int64",
                "@value": 200
            },
            "label": "key",
            "properties": {
                "EvenMoreSomethingElse": [{ // <== IMPORTANT, same as struct field in Bar{}
                    "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                    "@value": {
                        "id": {
                            "@type": "g:Int64",
                            "@value": 201
                        },
                        "value": true,
                        "label": "Write"
                    }
                }],
                "AndEvenMoreSomethingElse": [{ // <== IMPORTANT, same as struct field in Bar{}
                    "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                    "@value": {
                        "id": {
                            "@type": "g:Int64",
                            "@value": 202
                        },
                        "value": true,
                        "label": "Read"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Show an example of a `results` value.

Comment: If you want a single function without implementing an interface method on each type then the answer to your question is "with reflection".

Comment: @CeriseLimón updated the question.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for your answer, not sure I understand in this context.

Comment: Using package `reflect` you can get the field names of an arbitrary struct. Using the same package you can also set values on those fields if they are addressable and exported. More here: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/

Comment: Aha, yes, I understand that :-)
But how should I get the value to the function (where it now says `???`)